# SpringBoot Redis integration testing

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, redis

I have an application with `MySQL` and [SpringBoot](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/).

Redis is being used for caching with spring cache annotations.

Now, starting up Redis etc is not an issue as I am using Docker compose to dynamically allocate containers for testing.

But, what is the proper way of verifying that the data is actually being written and read from Redis cache not from `Mysql`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could prevent the client code to communicate with the MySQL database during the part of the integration test where you want to ensure that only Redis is used.
You don't precise the exact way to communicate with the MySQL database, so I cannot give you a specific advise.

But here some ideas :

- rely on an MySQL backend service implementation that throws exception as any method is invoked
- shutdown the MySQL database
- use an empty MySQL database

Comment: throwing exception seems like a good idea. So, I can mock my spring repository that is calling mysql, and throw exception on second invocation as this time the data should be returned from cache not from db. If it works, the we can say Redis integration is happening correctly. Will try to implement it now.

Answer (score 0):

To test it, I create the record from rest endpoint, then I remove it from the db using spring repository directly. Then, since it is cached, it is should  still be accessible by rest endpoint from cache even it is not present in the db.